# How to test apk on previous versions

Tags: android, version, apk, intel-xdk, android-install-apk

We developped an app for Android system with Intel xdk. Recently a customer tell us that it doesn't work on android 2.3 version. We would like to know how can we run the file apk on a 2.3 device for testing. If someone has some idea to help us we would be extremely grateful. Thanks

Comment: Buy an old device or test it on an emulator running 2.3?

Comment: try https://www.genymotion.com/ . work must faster than default emulator.

Comment: thank you, genymotion is useful, even if available version devices start from android 2.3.7 and we unfortunately need to test on android 2.3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the apk downloaded in your 2.3 version android device? 
If not, you could install it sending the apk in an email to the account in your android device, allow installations of apps from unknown sources in your settings in case that you didn't set that option before and follow the steps to install and run the app. Then you can test if the app is able to run in 2.3 version.

Comment: I have not a 2.3 version android device. I try to run the apk on genymotion and it works fine on 2.3.7. The customer's version android device is 2.3.6 and the available version devices on genymotion start from android 2.3.7. I think I need another emulator..

Comment: Or check this link http://techapple.net/2014/12/top-7-free-android-emulators-windows-788-110-pccomputer-run-android-appsgames-windows-78-110/

Answer (score 0):

Create different AVDs of different OS Versions and test the app in all AVDs.
Otherwise go for genymotion.